# How to segregate docker services when using celery?

Tags: docker, celery

I have a project with the following structure:

```
backend
|-app # fastapi and celery
|-scrapper # selenium and celery
```

I am using celery to run long and short tasks, so I will have multiple queues/workers. Also, I will have tasks called from `app`, but that will be processed by `scrapper`. I am thinking how to split things among containers and I am not sure how to proceed. Here is what I am thinking to do:

- one container to run fastapi
- one container for each worker related to the fastapi one. Each container here will be pretty much a copy of the fastapi one, but the entrypoint will be to run the celery worker
- one container to run the scrapper module
- one container for each worker related to the scrapper one. Each container here will be pretty much a copy of the scrapper one, but the entrypoint will be to run the celery worker

I am kinda new to docker and this seems to be a waste of resources (to have multiple copies of the same thing, one to run fastapi and another to run celery alone), but if I understood right this is the way to go. I that right?

Comment: I might run three containers – one for the API, one for the scraper, one for all of the workers together – but you can split this up whatever's appropriate for your workload and scaling needs.  The only really important rule is "one process per container".

Comment: Tks @DavidMaze. I guess in my case I would need two containers for the workers, since I have different code base for the API and scraper, rights?

Comment: If they're different code bases, then yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually have *four* different containers:

- fastapi
- fastapi-celery (worker(s) run with -Q fastapi)
- scraper
- scraper-celery (worker(s) run with -Q scraper)

Reason for this is simply the ability to manage and scale easily any piece of your infrastructure. At some point you may find that you do not have enough workers to handle heavy fastapi load - then you would just add more `fastapi-celery` containers, etc.